# Gridview scrolling mystically behave after notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, gridview, picasso

I created a GridView in which i load data. Data have a image link and i'm getting this link and put to Picasso for loading in ImageView.
I'm loading more data to the adapter when my GridView scrolling is end.
If adapter data have more 40 items, scrolling work mystically. 
When i stay in the middle position of adapter and trying scroll up, adapter move me to 1st position and all images refresh automatically.
Could anyone help me?

MyAdapter:

```
public class GridArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private static final String URL_SITE = "some url";
private List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;


public GridArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Movie> model) {
    super();
    this.movies = model;
    this.context = context;

}

public void addMovies(List<Movie> newMovies){
    this.movies.addAll(newMovies);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return movies.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    Holder holder;
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
        holder = new Holder();
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
    }
    com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
            .with(context)
            .load(URL_SITE + movies.get(position).getPosterPath())
            .into(holder.imageView);

    return convertView;
}
class Holder{
    ImageView imageView;
}}
```

Scrolling code:

```
        gridView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        private boolean canScroll = false;
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                canScroll = false;
            } else if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING ||
                    scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                canScroll = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if(firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == filmArray.size()&& canScroll) {
                canScroll = false;
                getPage(currentPage);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Getting data:

```
    private void getPage(Integer page){
    Call<Result> callPage = service.getPopularPage(++page, MovieDBApi.API_KEY);
    callPage.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, retrofit2.Response<Result> response) {
            currentPage = response.body().getPage();
            adapter.addMovies(response.body().getResults());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("onFailure", "Fail");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Remove the code in onScrollStateChanged(). You don't need to control the scroll state. You just need to recognize the last scroll of the list and call getPage().

Answer (score 1):

Your image refresh  because you don't use tag in your Picasso loading image. Should be:

```
com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
            .with(context)
            .load(URL_SITE + movies.get(position).getPosterPath())
            .tag(context)
            .into(holder.imageView);
```

YOu can read tagging in this [post](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/request-management-by-grouping-of-images-via-tag)

Why do you set `holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(null);`. You can remove it and try. But the image refreshing after you move too fast is very simple.